# Unity Deactivating a gameObject

Tags: unity, javascript

I'm trying to deactivate an GameObject when a certain variable reaches a certain value.
It is an imported FBX and doesnt have a MeshRenderer. I'm trying to stop it now with `TheGameObject.gameObject.activate = false;` then nothing happens.

Is there any other way to do this or fix this?

Answer (score 5):

The property is `active`, not `activate`.  And you can try using [`SetActiveRecursively`](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/GameObject.SetActiveRecursively.html) if your game object has multiple child objects.  Just setting the active flag doesn't set the active flags of child objects.